# DocumentsDirectory different in standalone iOS app

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently migrated an Expo app from SDK 32 to 35 and am experiencing a difference between the document directory.

Previously, when running the app in the Expo Client App or standalone (on SDK 32), FileSystem.documentDirectory would result in: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<BUILD_NO>/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/<APP_NAME>/`

In the new version of the app (on SDK 35) it will still provide the same documentDirectory when running in the Expo Client App but built as a standalone app it will use: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<BUILD_NO>/Documents/`

This is causing huge issues as our production app has documents stored in the previous directory.

More importantly, Expo has now generated another RCTAsyncLocalStorage directory meaning all values stored in AsyncStorage are no longer visible. I can see the old values under the previous directory, so they are not lost, just no longer visible to the application.

Is there any reason why this value would have changed, is there a changelog somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the Expo git history and found an answer.

It seems the directory was changed in SDK 33 and a migration was added for SDK's 33 and 34 but dropped in 35 meaning a migration from 32 to 35 is not supported and will require a manual renaming of the directory.